# Query http server known only by IP for TLS common name and subject alternative name(s)?

Tags: java, http, ssl

Suppose I know that a server's IP address is 1.2.3.4 (made up for this example)

If I go to https://www.digicert.com/help/ and do a search for that address, it might return something like:

```
Common Name = fqdn.org
Organization = somebody
City/Locality = Somewhere
State/Province = Somestate
Country = US
Subject Alternative Names = www.fqdn.org, another.fqdn.org
....
```

Is there any straightforward way to accomplish something similar (querying a http server for the common name and any SANs associated with its certificate, given only its IP address) using Java?

Comment: There's nothing that easy in Java, no. There are certainly ways to do it.

Comment: Assuming it's an https server and not just http -- `keytool -printcert -sslserver name_OR_addr[:port]` will print all details of the cert chain the server sends, including CommonName (Owner: ... CN= ...) and SAN (SubjectAlternativeName) -- but note if SAN is present all clients including Java/JSSE _will_ ignore CommonName. And if the server uses SNI to choose the cert chain, this may obtain and print the _wrong_ cert chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do this in a few cases with very small services that don't use CDNs or similar, but in general this isn't possible to do perfectly, and probably won't work at all most of the time.

This isn't a Java limitation, but a TLS limitation. All modern TLS servers use [server name indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) where the client tells the server in its first message which domain name it's looking for. This is because many servers host multiple domains, each of which has a different certificate, so if you don't request a specific certificate then they won't know which one to send to you.

If you connect to an IP without telling the server which certificate you're looking for, it will probably either reject you, or send you a default fallback certificate, which may not be related to the one you're looking for.

If you want to test this, you can do so with OpenSSL directly, like so:

```bash
$ openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
# Makes a TLS connection, including google.com in SNI
# Returns a lot of certificate info for google.com

$ openssl s_client -connect 142.250.201.78:443
# Makes a TLS connection to the same IP with no domain SNI
# (This is just one of many IPs, but it's the one I resolve locally)
# Connection rejected with a "No SNI provided" invalid certificate.
```

To make this worse, nowadays a large majority of sites (especially major ones) use services like Cloudflare in front of their servers. In this case, a single IP might support hundreds of thousands of different unrelated domains for all their different customers. Unfortunately that means there's no way you're going to get useful information back from that IP by making a single request.

Comment: Oddly, [www.]google.com does this only for TLS1.3, which you are probably using by default; add `-no_tls1_3` (or use OpenSSL below 1.1.1) and you will get a valid cert usually(?) with SAN containing maybe a hundred entries for various google properties. And stackoverflow/superuser/serverfault/*.stackexchange always works without SNI (using Fastly not Cloudflare). Several Azure domains I've tried without SNI give a valid cert -- but sometimes for _other_ Azure domains!